# How can I get a notification if wget can not reach a site in x seconds?

Tags: linux, wget

How can I set a timeout for `wget` and get a notification the connection times out in 20 seconds?

So far I've tried the following command

```
   wget  --spider www.example.com
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: @Bruno9779 sorry for my english. i want to get any alert if  url doesnt response in time limit.

Comment: what is the context you are using wget? as part of a script? or raw command line?

Comment: @Bruno9779 on command line.

Comment: Wow, downvote-fest! Come on guys, if you are going to downvote at least have the decency to explain why so that people can improve their questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -T 20 --spider www.example.com || ping -n 1 www.example.com
```

However, ICMP/pings aren't always useful for determining site availability since they have been used in distributed denial of service attacks since the beginning of the century.

Comment: thnx to you. i did it!